# Injecting from one EJB module to another

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.1

When I try to access EJB from another module inside one Application I got NullPointerException.

I'll explain an example to be more exact.

EAR Structure following:

```
EAR
|
— core.jar (EJB-module with core EJB) — application core
|
— app.jar (another EJB-module with EJBs) —  business logic here
| 
— web.war (servlets)
```

At code.jar there is EJB:

```
@LocalBean
@Singleton
@Startup
public class AppInfo(){
   private int counter;

   public void incCounter(){
     counter++;
  }
  public int getCounterValue(){
    return counter;
  }    
}
```

At module app.jar we have Stateless EJB which tries to read counter.

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBean{
   @EJB private AppInfo appinfo;

    public void run(){
       int counter = appInfo.getCounterValue(); // here method throws with NPE
       System.out.println("Counter value is: "+counter);
   }   
}
```

At module web.war there is servlet that increment counter value for every request:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
        @EJB private AppInfo appInfo;
        protected void doPost(params){
              appInfo.incCounter();
              ...
              other code
       }
  }
```

While debugging, I detected that:
At servlet injection work well: when entering doPost() appInfo is Proxy object for AppInfo EJB.
At SomeBean there is NPE: at run() entry point value of appInfo = null.

How I do correctly inject EJB from core.jar to another EJB from App?

P.S. I deploy EAR to JBoss 6.1 EAP 
P.S.S. I also tried using @Remote: not working (appInfo is still equals null)

Answer (score 0):

I think Local should work - this is in the same Application.

Try the fully qualified package name:

```
@EJB(beanName="my.package.AppInfo")
```

Comment: We are using EJB 3.1, so as I suppose `@Local` is not needed anymore and also we using `@LocalBean` instead of defining `@Local` interface

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that this is a JBoss deployment ordering issue. When the container creates a new instance of `SomeBean` and tries to inject the `AppInfo` bean, this one hasn't been created/deployed yet.

Try to rename your jars file, indicating the correct dependency order. (eg. a_core.jar and b_app.jar).

Other possibility could be to inject the singleton bean on a [setter method](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Dependency_Injection.html).

Answer (score -2):

To access EJB from another module, you need to do with following ways:

1. Use `Remote` access instead of `Local` access. or
2. Use `JNDI`.

For details, read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html).

Comment: Well, I say again: I also tried using @Remote: not working (appInfo is still equals null)

Comment: `Use Remote access instead of Local access` you don't need that, and you absolutely shouldn't do this ever for any reason at all. Remote is used for a very specific purpose, and injecting an EJB from a different module in the same EAR is not it. Don't do this ever.